# Selenium - are ExpectedConditions reliable? eg visibility, clickabiliy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

how reliable are Selenium’s `ExpectedConditions`, namely the abilities to tell whether or not an element is clickable or visible?

(eg `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`, and

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`)

several years ago i had some frustration with these tools and have been essentially re-inventing the wheel since then, to accomplish the same goals.

I'm wondering, today: **are these `ExpectedConditions` reliable against all webpages?**

if not, **when should they be avoided?**

and, **when can they be trusted?**

that is, have they ever caused you grief also?  if so, when? vs. when have they worked?  by "when", i mean which flavors of html/javascript

Comment: If you have a problem file a bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues

Comment: @SiKing i just found your blog, it's awesome.  thank you for yr comment and for publishing your experiences -- super helpful